# How to execute callback function while resursive function is running in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, callback, stack

It is impossible to run callback function while recursive function is running?

It is sample code of reculsive fibonacci function and setInterval()

```
'use strict';

function fibo(x) {
  if (x === 0) {
    console.info('fibo( ' + x + ' ) == 0');
    return 0;
  } else if (x === 1) {
    console.info('fibo( ' + x + ' ) == 1');
    return 1;
  }
  return fibo(x-2) + fibo(x-1);
};

fibo(10);

setInterval(() =>{console.info('hello')},10);
```

Excuting this code, setInterval run after fibo(10) finished its work.

How to display 'hello' log while fibo() is running?
Is it possible to cut in callback function while recursive function is running?

Comment: `setInterval` and `setTimeout` calls run after all the synchronous calls are complete. Same will happen if you will run a long `for` or `while` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to display 'hello' log while fibo() is running?

Since `fibo` is synchronous, you can't in the normal case. JavaScript works on the basis of threads servicing a job queue. While one job is running, no other jobs can run on that thread (such as the ones queued by `setInterval` to call your callback). There's only one thread per *realm* (loosely, global environment), and there's only one main thread in all major environments (including browsers). You can create others, but they have their own environment.

You have a couple of options:

1. Make `fibo` asynchronous, where each call to it schedules the next in another job (via `setTimeout` for instance).
2. Make `fibo` a generator function, and call it repeatedly for the values, interspersing those calls with your `setInterval` callback.
3. Use a worker thread.

Since your `setInterval` code and your `fibo` code don't share any data, using a worker thread makes sense:

`main.js`:

```
'use strict';

function fibo(x) {
  if (x === 0) {
    console.info('fibo( ' + x + ' ) == 0');
    return 0;
  } else if (x === 1) {
    console.info('fibo( ' + x + ' ) == 1');
    return 1;
  }
  return fibo(x-2) + fibo(x-1);
};

new Worker("worker.js");
fibo(10);
```

`worker.js`:

```
setInterval(() =>{console.info('hello')},10);
```

If they shared data, you might use [shared memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) for it, but beware of synchronization issues.

Comment: @GrossMatt - If you're doing to make `fibo` asynchronous, you need to keep track of state somewhere (a stack-like structure). Beware that it will also run a lot slower.

Comment: Recursive function is just a example of a function which takes very long time to be ended. If My web service running on javascript server has both heavy work like realtime 3d rendering and light work like CRUD, I should make heavy work asynchronous because JS can do only one thing at the same time. Is there a general solution to make big while loop or recursive function asynchronous?

Comment: @GrossMatt - The general solution is "break the work up into chunks and do one chunk at a time." But in the situation you describe, I'd use a worker thread or child process for the 3D rendering. With a web server (or any server), you want to avoid blocking the thread(s) doing the serving.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I think JS is more complex than I thought. Make animation in single page using DOM wasn't that difficult, but node.JS serverside programming is not that simple....